# Android Studio: ToggleButton - How to start/awake with true instead of false?

Tags: java, android, xml

-Using Android Studio

In my activity_main.xml,

```
  android:checked="false"
```

would android:checked="" be the reason why my ToggleButton starts (or awakens) with false when my application compiles and runs?  Changing to true seems to not work.  My goal is to start with the ON button (or True) whenever my application boots instead of the OFF (or false) button but I have no idea how make this happen.  Any ideas?  Doesn't matter if it's through java or xml.

Also I am using,

```
  android:background="@drawable/toggle_sound"
```

in order to import the images to the ToggleButton, which I successfully managed to do so.

In my toggle_sound.xml:

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/sound_on" android:state_checked="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/sound_off" android:state_checked="false"></item>
```

Additionally, this is my entire method of ToggleButton inside activity_main.xml:

```
 <ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toggleSound"
    android:background="@drawable/toggle_sound"
    android:textOff=""
    android:textOn=""
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:checked="false" />
```

Again, any solution either through java or xml will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use a Java solution, then it's easy!

In your onCreate method, just set it to false!

```
ToggleButton mToggle;

protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    mToggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.my_toggle_button);
    mToggle.setChecked(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This work each and every time!

```
  android:checked="true"
```

You can go with java too, as depicted by Alek K. But if you want your application to always start will true(togglebutton ON) then you can go with XML one.